# Swift: How to handle view controllers for my game

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

i have a general question about view controllers and how to handle them in a clean way when i develop a SpriteKit based game.

What i did so far:

- Use storyboard only for defining view controllers
- SKScene's are presented in each view controller (Home, LevelSelection, Game) by presentScene
- in each view controller i call **performSegueWithIdentifier** with the identifier i defined in the storyboard between the view controllers
- all the content i show programmatically using SKSpritenode etc. on the SKScene's
- on the storyboard i only have view controllers with segue relations and identifiers defined
- all the stuff i do in viewDidDisappear is because it seems to be the only way to get my SKScene deinited correctly

My problems are:

- everytime i segue to another view, my memory raises, because the view controller is re-initialized, the old one keeps staying in the stack
- it is not clear for me how to handle the segue's between the view controllers, on some tutorial pages i see people using the navigation controller, others are using strong references of some view controllers and using the singleton pattern for the view controller in order to decide either to init the view controller or just show it
- my view controllers are not deiniting, i understand my home view can't because it is the initial one, but since ios is reiniting it anyways, why then not unloading it?

What is the correct way for a Swift based game using SpriteKit to handle the view controller? Below you can see my initial view controller (Home) showing an SKScene with a simple play button which calls the play() function to segue to the levelselection

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class Home : UIViewController {
    private var scene : HomeScene!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print(self)
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.scene = HomeScene(size: view.bounds.size)
        self.scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        let skView = view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(play), name: Constants.Events.Home.play, object: nil)

        skView.presentScene(self.scene)
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        let v = view as! SKView
        self.scene.dispose()
        v.presentScene(nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
        self.scene = nil
        self.view = nil
        print("home did disappear")
    }

    func play() {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("home_to_levelselection", sender: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        print("Home_VC deinit")
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds to me like poor level design,  unless you plan on using multiple views for multiple purposes, stick to 1 view controlller with 1 skview, and just use presentScene to bounce between different scenes

Comment: As always you are the master at stack overflow. Always the correct advice when I see you.

Comment: Interesting, im just doing what i saw from all the tutorials and even app templates i downloaded. i always saw multiple views like Home, Settings, GameScreen and GameOver. Isn't it too hard to handle EVERYTHING with just one ViewController? @Knight0fDragon can you tell me some site where i can read about this idea?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not,  but no, it is not hard to handle everything in 1 view controller.  The easiest way I can think about this is your view controller and your view are pretty much shells for the Sprite Kit environment, and you should be treating your scene files like they are your "view controllers".  The only issue is you do not have a nice GUI setup yet to handle multiple scenes like you do with the story board.  Maybe in future updates of XCode, scene editor will allow for it.

Comment: Did you not read my answer?

Comment: I did, was answering Knight0fDragon before i read yours. Thanks for the answer. I already changed my code and everything works like a charm, memory is not raising anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your way seems very complicated to essentially present 3 scenes. Its not what you are supposed to do for SpriteKit games, you only really need 1 view controller (GameViewController).

Load your first scene from GameViewController (e.g HomeScene) and nothing else.
Create your playButton and other UI directly in HomeScene. Use SpriteKit APIs for your UI (SKLabelNodes, SKNodes, SKSpriteNodes etc).

You should never really use UIKit (UIButtons, UILabels) in SpriteKit. There are some exceptions to this, like maybe using UICollectionViews for massive level select menus, but basic UI should be done with SpriteKit APIs.

There is plenty tutorials to google on how to create sprite kit buttons, how to use SKLabelNodes etc. Xcode has a SpriteKit level editor so you can do all that visually similar to storyboards.

Than from HomeScene transition to the LevelSelect Scene and than to the GameScene and vice versa. Its super easy to do.

```
/// Home Scene
class HomeScene: SKScene {

  ...

   func loadLevelSelectScene() {

       // Way 1
       // code only, no XCode/SpriteKit visual level editor used
       let scene = LevelSelectScene(size: self.size) // same size as current scene 

       // Way 2
       // with xCode/SpriteKit visual level editor
       // fileNamed is the LevelSelectScene.sks you need to create that goes with your LevelSelectScene class. 
       guard let scene = LevelSelectScene(fileNamed: "LevelSelectScene") else { return }        


       let transition = SKTransition.SomeTransitionYouLike
       view?.presentScene(scene, withTransition: transition)
    }  
}

/// Level Select Scene
class LevelSelectScene: SKScene {
   ....

     func loadGameScene() {

        // Way 1
        // code only, no XCode/SpriteKit visual level editor used
        let scene = GameScene(size: self.size) // same size as current scene 

        // Way 2
        // with xCode/SpriteKit visual level editor
        // fileNamed is the GameScene.sks you need to create that goes with your GameScene class. 
        guard let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") else { return }


       let transition = SKTransition.SomeTransitionYouLike
       view?.presentScene(scene, withTransition: transition)
    } 
}

/// Game Scene
class GameScene: SKScene {
   ....
}
```

I strongly recommend you scratch your storyboard and ViewController approach, and just use different SKScenes and 1 GameViewController.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, works great. I now have only one view controller and multiple scenes. Im actually disposing the current scene everytime i present the new scene and reinit when i jump back. The only exception will be when i hit the pause button on my GameScene, i will show some popup view while GameScene is paused, will figure out how to do that. But this question is answered.

Comment: Awesome, and you are welcome. In regards to the popup menu, the easiest and cleanest way is to create a subclass of SKSpriteNode or SKNode. Give it the size you want and just ad your pause label, resume button etc to that class.  Than just add the menu class to the scene when needed. You can use SKActions to animate it, fade it in etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try that.

Comment: You are welcome. If you have troubles just ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the segues and use Show Detail Segues anywhere that you don't want the previous view controller to be kept in the stack. Keep in mind that you will have to reinitialize everything appropriately in those view controllers whenever you do return to them.

If you pay attention, `viewDidAppear` loads every time that you see the view appear, while with your current setup, `viewDidLoad` would only be called initially and if you returned to the `viewController`, only `viewDidAppear` would be called.

When you use a segue to transition out of a `viewController`, `prepareForSegue` is called, but `deinit()` is only called when you use a show detail segue (or custom segue with those specific properties about it), because the view, like you said, is loaded into memory so it can be retrieved easier.

Comment: I know you have tried to answer the question, but its portably better to advice the OP against this approach as its not what you are supposed to do in SpriteKit.

Comment: @crashoverride777 Why would using  SpriteKit use a different approach? Retaining view state is way more important?

Comment: Ohhhhh, well, I answered his question. You gave him a better question to ask and answered it =P

Comment: Sorry I was just saying, better to recommend the correct approach than to use the wrong one. SpriteKit is different than UIKit. In UIKit you use ViewControllers for UI whereas in SpriteKit you use SKScenes for UI (only 1 viewController that presents the scenes). A scene automatically deallocates when you transition to a new one and since you only have 1 view controller it doesn't need to deallocate. Have a look at apples sample game DemoBots. The way the OP is trying to make his SpriteKit game is incorrect.

Comment: I will know more about it than the next guy within a week of ever needing to use it. I'm just very focussing on my current skill set.

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to say. I am not criticising you or questioning your skills. I merely offered a suggestion that will also benefit future readers.

Comment: Sorry, I appreciate the advise and your time! I'm in a weird mood.

Comment: Dont worry. Imagine I was trying to create a regular app like youtube, Facebook etc and I was asking a question that was trying to use SKScenes with SpriteKit APIs. You would be like dont do that, use UIKit and storyboards. We are all here to help each other. Happy coding.