# How to create endless scrolling background with scenes switching in SpriteKit ?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game which possess upto 5 different scenes(levels). However there are multiple scenes, I would want to have only one endless background scrolling forever, even when i transition from one scene to another.

Couldn't find anything on google so expect the answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Its always good practice to post some code of what you have tried before when asking a question on stack overflow. People tend to not help when you show no code.

Since you cannot have multiple SKScenes running at the same time and scenes start in a clean state (unless you archive the whole scene) you will most like have to use your current set up for the scrolling background and use it for all scenes. You can use protocol extensions or subclassing to share the code.

As KingOfDragon has so kindly pointed out, you can try playing around with SKTransitions, such as pushInDirection to get the desired result.

If that doesn't work and you want the scrolling background to resume at the exact spot in a new scene you could create some property that stores the current background position before a scene change. Than after the scene change you set the background to the new position so it looks the same.

Im not sure what your setup is but of the top if my head it could be something like this

Create a global property above any scene class

```
 let bgPosition = CGPoint()
```

Than create a protocol extension for your scrolling background code to make it reusable

```
protocol ScrollingBackground { }
extension ScrollingBackground where Self: SKScene {

     func loadScrollingBackground(at position: CGPoint) {
        /// your code for the scrolling background 
        /// set position to position you pass in function 

     }
```

Than in your first scene you conform to the protocol and set your scrolling background as usual.
Than add the WillMoveFromView method that gets called upon scene transition. There set the bgPosition property to your last position of the scrolling background.

```
   class Scene1: SKScene, ScrollingBackground {

        ....
        let backgroundPosition = ....
        loadScrollingBackground(at: backgroundPosition)



        override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
            bgPosition = ... //Set to current position of scrolling background     
       }
  }
```

Than in your other scenes you do the same but pass in the bgPosition property (as mentioned above) to set the background to the position it was in Scene1.

```
   class Scene2: SKScene, ScrollingBackground {

        ....
        loadScrollingBackground(at: bgPosition)
  }
```

Not sure this is exactly what you are looking but something like this is probably the easiest way.

Hope this helps

Comment: You can have 2 scenes running at the same time when you transition,  so if you do it correctly, you can achieve what the OP wants

Comment: My guess is to use `SKTransition.pushWithDirection` to achieve the desired effect he is going for

Comment: Thats true, I forgot about the scene transitions. I was just taking a shot in the dark, not sure how the OP has set up his scrolling background.

Comment: That is fine,  I do not think that the OP should be using multiple scenes, but I am not going to dictate his code lol.

Comment: Exactly, thats why I just came up with a quick solution saving the background position before changing scenes.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon man you got me confused !! Will you please mind expaining explicitly.

Comment: not sure how,  the comments weren't for you,  I was letting @crashoverride777 know that you can have 2 scenes running when you transition

Comment: @crashoverride777 bro I got u but what about the during transition period?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon so u mean to say u dont know how to do what i want? C'mon man you seem to be experienced, its going to be my first game in spritekit man. Don't hesitate from sharing the knowledge you have !!

Comment: When you transition from 1 SKScene to another 1 you can use a SKTransitions. Some transitions, like pushWithDirection, or cross fade can help you in achieving your results. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085221/swift-how-to-handle-view-controllers-for-my-game/39087238#39087238

Comment: You haven't post any code or anything so we can only guess and offer suggestions. You should always post code here and what you tried so far.

Comment: @Ayush Rajput  No idea what you are talking about, I never said that.  Of course I know how to do what you want,  I can do it 10+ different ways.  Your question is not concrete enough to make a valid answer,  I do not write code for other people without some kind of payment,  I provide ideas and examples to help them solve their problems.