# TVOS : detecting touches with press began and functions (Swift Spritekit)

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, tvos

im trying to define touches in TVOS with press began but its not working.

i want to connect 3 functions

- Start Game
- Play Pause Music
- Restart Game

**Game scene TVOS:**

```
 func StartGameRecognizer(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        if isGameOver {
        } else if !isStarted {
            start()
        } else {
            hero.flip()
        }

    }

 func playPauseMusicRecognizer(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

            let onoroff = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "onoroff")

            if !onoroff { //playing is false
                Singleton.sharedInstance().pauseBackgroundMusic()
                SoundOnOff.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Sound-off.png")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "onoroff")
            }
            else {
                Singleton.sharedInstance().resumeBackgroundMusic()
                SoundOnOff.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Sound-on.png")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "onoroff")
            }
        }

func RestartGameRecognizer(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    print("RestartGame")
    //Re-open GameScene

    GameViewController().TitleGameOver.isHidden = true
    GameViewController().RestartButton.isHidden = true
    GameViewController().scoreTextLabel.isHidden = true
    GameViewController().highscoreTextLabel.isHidden = true
    GameViewController().ScoreBoardTV.isHidden = true
    GameViewController().Score.isHidden = true
    GameViewController().HighScore.isHidden = true
    GameViewController().NewhighscoreTextLabel.isHidden = true
    GameViewController().HomeButton.isHidden = true
    // Singleton.sharedInstance().resumeSoundEffectClickedButton()
    GameViewController().gameDidStart()


}
```

**GameViewControllerTVOS:**

```
 override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    for press in presses {
        switch press.type {
        case .upArrow:
            print("Up Arrow")
        case .downArrow:
            print("Down arrow")
        case .leftArrow:
            print("Left arrow")
        case .rightArrow:
            print("Right arrow")
        case .select:
            print("Select")
        case .menu:
            print("Menu")
        case .playPause:
            print("Play/Pause")

        default:
        print("")
        }
    }
}
```

- How i can use it right?
- How can i transfer functions between scene to view controller?

I need example or hint to write the code right.

**Update:**

**GameSceneTvOS:**

```
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameSceneTVOS.StartGameRecognizer(gesture:)))
        tapGesture.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.Select.rawValue)]
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        let tapGesture1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameSceneTVOS.PlaypauseMusicRecognizer(gesture:)))
        tapGesture1.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.PlayPause.rawValue)]
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture1)

        let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameSceneTVOS.RestartGameRecognizer(gesture:)))
        swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up
        self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
}

**Functions :**

func StartGameRecognizer(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("StartGame")

            if isGameOver {
                } else if !isStarted {
                    start()
                } else {
                    hero.flip()
                }

            }

    func PlaypauseMusicRecognizer(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("PlaypauseMusic")


       let onoroff = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "onoroff")

        if !onoroff { //playing is false
            Singleton.sharedInstance().pauseBackgroundMusic()
            SoundOnOff.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Sound-off.png")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "onoroff")
        }
        else {
            Singleton.sharedInstance().resumeBackgroundMusic()
            SoundOnOff.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Sound-on.png")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "onoroff")
        }
    }


    func RestartGameRecognizer(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        print("RestartGame")
        //Re-open GameScene

        GameViewController().TitleGameOver.isHidden = true
        GameViewController().RestartButton.isHidden = true
        GameViewController().scoreTextLabel.isHidden = true
        GameViewController().highscoreTextLabel.isHidden = true
        GameViewController().ScoreBoardTV.isHidden = true
        GameViewController().Score.isHidden = true
        GameViewController().HighScore.isHidden = true
        GameViewController().NewhighscoreTextLabel.isHidden = true
        GameViewController().HomeButton.isHidden = true
        // Singleton.sharedInstance().resumeSoundEffectClickedButton()
        GameViewController().gameDidStart()


    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You code has some problems.

1) This code is wrong in the restartGame method.

```
  GameViewController().TitleGameOver.isHidden = true
  GameViewController().RestartButton.isHidden = true
  ...
```

You are creating a new instance of GameViewController on every line, you are not referencing the current game view controller.

2) You should not be using your GameViewController to create your UI, you should be doing it directly in the relevant SKScenes using only SpriteKit APIs (SKLabelNodes, SKSpriteNodes, SKNodes etc). Using UIKit in SpriteKit, except in some occasions, is bad practice.

3) You should be using TouchesBegan, TouchesMoved etc directly in the SKScenes to get touch input, dont use the GameViewController method. 
They fill fire just like they do when you are on iOS.

You can also create gesture recognizers in your SKScene to get button presses from the SiriRemote.

```
/// Pressed, not tapped, main touch pad
let pressedMain = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SOMEMETHOD))
pressedMain.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.select.rawValue)]
view?.addGestureRecognizer(pressedMain)

/// Pressed play pause button
let pressedPlayPause = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SOMEMETHOD))
pressedPlayPause.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.playPause.rawValue)]
view?.addGestureRecognizer(pressedPlayPause)

 /// Pressed menu button
let pressedMenu = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SOMEMETHOD))
pressedMenu.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.menu.rawValue)]
view?.addGestureRecognizer(pressedMenu)
```

You can also use swipe gesture recognizers if you want

```
let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SOMEMETHOD))
rightSwipe.direction = .right
view?.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SOMEMETHOD))
leftSwipe.direction = .left
view?.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

let upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SOMEMETHOD))
upSwipe.direction = .up
view?.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)

let downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SOMEMETHOD))
downSwipe.direction = .down
view?.addGestureRecognizer(downSwipe)
```

If you are using gesture recognisers, remember they are added to the GameViewController (view?.addGesture...) so its good practice to remove them when you add either new ones, or if you change to a new scene where you might need different ones.

Call this code when you exit a scene or add new gesture recognizers.

```
 for gestureRecognizer in view?.gestureRecognizers ?? [] {
        view?.removeGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
```

If you are looking for fully fledged micro gamepad support than you will need to watch some tutorials about the gameController framework.

4) Try putting your string keys like the ones for UserDefaults in some property.

```
 enum Key: String {
     case onoroff
 }
```

and than use it like so

```
 UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: Key.onoroff.rawValue)
```

to avoid making typos.

5) You should be following the Swift conventions consistently, some of your methods and properties start with capital letters but they shouldn't.

I would advise that you restructure your code and not continue with this approach of trying to use the GameViewController for all this. It should be all done directly in the relevant SKScene.

EDIT. I think you are calling the selector wrong, try this. When your function has a parameter you would use this (_:), you are trying to use (gesture:). Try this instead.

```
 ... action: #selector(startGameRecognizer(_:))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i can't to define Select and Play/Pause its not working

Comment: You need to add this in DidMoveToView in your Scene.

Comment: This what I did , it's not responding too in console

Comment: You should take a step back and fix your code first. Your sample code can absolutely not be used in production. This includes deleting everything you have in GameViewController apart from the default code. Recreate your UI in your SKScenes first and than try again with the gestures for tv controls.

Comment: I did and only swipe not working on simulator , tap works!

Comment: For swipe you can usually use touches moved. The trackpad on the siri remote will call TouchesBegan, TouchesMoved, TouchesCancelled, TouchesEnded automatically in your SKSenes. Its the same as if you are developing an iPhone game and want touch input. The gestures is an easy way to recognize if you actually press (not tap) the trackpad, pause/play or the menu button. I will update my answer if you want specific swipe gestures, thats possible too. Give me 1 minute.

Comment: Yes, I want to use with swipe up gesture. thanks you

Comment: Ok , I putted print("RestartGame") but its not appear on console.

Comment: I dunno, its very basic code. Add it at the same spot where you added the other gesture recognisers in your SKScene. Make sure you deleted the override func pressesBegan method in your GameViewController.

Comment: i deleted the method pressesBegan from GameViewController

Comment: I dunno I can only take a guess. Can you update your question with your new code both for GameViewController and your SKScene with my suggestions. Do not delete your current question, just add the new code at the bottom.

Comment: Ok i added what i changed

Comment: Where to put this ? for gestureRecognizer in view?.gestureRecognizers ?? [] {
        view?.removeGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }

Comment: Normally you call that when you add new recognisers or when you change scene and dont need them anymore. There also seems to actually be no mistake with your code, it was just the formatting that put me off.

Comment: Check my edited answer at the end, I believe you are calling the #selector wrong.

Comment: And you are still trying to do this GameViewController()... so you haven't changed your code.

Comment: You are not reading my answer. You are creating a new instance of GameViewController on every line, you are not calling your current instance. You should NOT use UILabels, UIButtons and other UIKit APIs at all, you should be creating your UI with SKLabelNodes, SKSpriteNodes etc directly in your SKScenes.

Comment: I know and this what I did.

Comment: No you are not . You still have your labels and button created in your GameViewController with UIKit and than try call them like so GameViewController().TitleGameOver.isHidden = true

Comment: Maybe take my email : omerharel19@gmail.com write me and explain me what I do not fine

Comment: I am not really bothered to explain all this. It means that you have not read/watched any basic SpriteKit tutorials. SKLabelNodes = https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/games/how-to-write-text-using-sklabelnode    Buttons = https://nathandemick.com/2014/09/buttons-sprite-kit-using-swift/

Comment: you need to see my code and maybe understand why i did it. team viewer?

Comment: I know exactly what you did. You created all your UI in GameViewController using UIKit and than from your scene your are trying to call them like so GameViewController().someLabel.... . First that code will not work because you are creating a new instance of GameViewController and secondly you should not even be trying to do this because your UI should be done in the SKScenes. So before you even continue with Touch input you should delete ALL your labels and buttons code from GameViewController and recreate them in your SKScenes with SKLabelNodes, SKSpriteNodes etc.

Comment: In your #selector method replace gesture with a _ and see what happens. You should really fix your game before continuing with the SiriRemote.

Comment: Fix your UI like I suggested before continuing. Before your project grows bigger and bigger

Comment: Cool. Your GameViewController should basically have no code apart from the default code you get with the game template. Everything should be done in the SKScenes. You got to imagine that GameViewController is managing all your scenes. So if you have multiple scenes, which you will eventually have, than all your labels will be show on all scenes and you will have to manually remove them. And it will be madness. If you use SpriteKit APIs you dont have to worry about any of this, a Scene always starts in a clean state.

Comment: If the selector stuff still doesn't work google #selector syntax in swift.

Comment: In SpriteKit on TvOS I need to use only in game scene. No gameviewcontroller

Comment: Yeah you never really use GameViewController in SpriteKit games. GameViewControllers only job is to present/manage all the Scenes and thats pretty much it. You only have 1 GameScene at the moment, but what happens when you need a MenuScene, a ShopScene, or a SettingsScene etc?.  With your old way everything would start to fall apart at that point because your labels would show up in all the scenes. Thats why you should only use SpriteKit APIs like SKLabelNodes, SKSpriteNodes so that doesn't happen.

Comment: You should also read this question I answered recently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085221/swift-how-to-handle-view-controllers-for-my-game/39087238#39087238

Comment: Hi , I fixed all but the swipe up to restart game not working.

Comment: Dunno check your if statement. What you wrote doesn't really make sense "        if isGameOver {
                } else if !isStarted {
                    start()
                } else {
                    hero.flip()
                }

            }"

Comment: Are you calling the right selector in the swip up gesture?

Comment: Maybe i need to use with UIButton to restart my game ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use UISwipeGestureRecognizer or UITapGestureRecognizer gestures.

Also, make sure you disable any touch logic if you're using the remote. Touching the tvOS remote will trigger touches began.

Utilize pressesBegan to invoke the function in the dPadUp, dpadDown, aAction, bAction, etc.

```
extension GameViewController {
    
    // MARK: - tvOS Controls -

    override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {

        var didHandleEvent = false
        
        for press in presses {
            
            #if os(tvOS)
            
            // tvOS
            
            if press.type == .select {
                
                // click touch pad
                
                print("select")
                
                self.aAction()
                
            } else if press.type == .menu {
                
                // menu button
                
                print("menu")
                
            } else if press.type == .playPause {
                
                // play pause
                
                self.bAction()
                
                print("playPause")
                
            } else if press.type == .upArrow {
                
                // upArrow
                
                print("upArrow")
                
                self.dPadUp()
                
            } else if press.type == .leftArrow {
                
                // leftArrow
                
                print("leftArrow")
                
                self.dPadLeft()
                
            } else if press.type == .downArrow {
                
                // downArrow
                
                print("downArrow")
                
                self.dPadDown()
                
            } else if press.type == .rightArrow {
                
                // rightArrow
                
                print("rightArrow")
                
                self.dPadRight()
                
            }
                
            if #available(tvOS 14.3, *) {

                if press.type == .pageUp {
                    
                    // pageUp
                    
                    print("pageUp")
                    
                } else if press.type == .pageDown {
                    
                    // pageDown
                    
                    print("pageDown")
                    
                }
                
            }
            
            #endif

        }

        if didHandleEvent == false {
            
            // Didn't handle this key press, so pass the event to the next responder.

            super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)

        }

    }
    
    // MARK: - Keyboard -
    
    @objc func dPadUp() {
        
        print("up")
                
    }
    
    @objc func dPadLeft() {
        
        print("left")
        
    }
    
    @objc func dPadRight() {
        
        print("right")
        
    }
    
    @objc func dPadDown() {
        
        print("down")
                        
    }
    
    @objc func idleButton() {
        
        print("idle")
                
    }
    
    @objc func aAction() {
        
        print("aAction")
                
    }
    
    @objc func xAction() {
        
        print("xAction")
                
    }
    
    @objc func yAction() {
        
        print("yAction")
                
    }

    @objc func bAction() {
        
        print("bAction")
                        
    }
        
}
```